# Do i need many Adapters for many Recyclerviews?

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am learning how to properly develop android apps. Right now im working on an app which should show different Fragments with different Recyclerviews. Until now i only had a single Recyclerview with a single Adapter. In the Adapter, the Textviews from the Recyclerview are getting assigned through a ViewHolder.

Now my Question: How does this work? Do i need a new Adapter for a different Recyclerview or is it possible to "fill" the TextViews from many Recyclerviews from one SINGLE adapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all your ListViews or RecyclerViews show the same data with the same Textviews and ImageViews etc, then you could reuse your adapter.

However if they do not use the data in the exact same way, you should make a new adapter with his own functionality.

Because chances are slim that you have multiple lists showing the exact same data, it is usually so that each ListView or RecyclerView has their own dedicated adapter.

---

You could make it so that an adapter checks to what it belongs (which ListView or RecyclerView) and use the data depending in that check, but that is nasty and conflicts with the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: I thoughrt about the single adapter with "belong-checks".. but as you say ..  it's nasty.. :)
 I'll make additional Adapters.
I'll mark this as answer as soon as its possible.

Comment: @CodingJohn Good choice. Also in this case, if one of the lists' functionality should ever change, you don't have to worry about other stuff breaking - since they all have their own adapter

Comment: Yeah thats true.. And its easer to reuse some code if you've done it this way :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a super class Adapter, and extend it to use for different cases. This gives a possibility to write less code and reuse things that are in the super class.

Here is a example from my project (super abstract RecyclerViewAdapter with filter possibility):

```
public abstract class GenericRecycleAdapter<T, K extends Holders.TextImageHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements Filterable {
    private final Context context;
    protected List<T> mList = new ArrayList<T>() {
    };
    private List<T> originalData = null;
    private Action1<List> task;
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    private int lastPosition;

    public GenericRecycleAdapter(List<T> list, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        if (list != null) {
            this.mList = list;
        }

        this.originalData = list;
    }


    public void refresh(List<T> list) {
        if (list != null) {
            this.mList = list;
        }
        this.originalData = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public T getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(getLayout(), parent, false);
        return getCustomHolder(v);
    }

    public Holders.TextImageHolder getCustomHolder(View v) {
        return new Holders.TextImageHolder(v) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onItem(mList.get(this.getAdapterPosition()));
                onPosition(this.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        };
    }

    protected void onPosition(int position) {

    }

    protected abstract void onItem(T t);

    public abstract int getLayout();

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        onSet(mList.get(position), (K) holder);
        onSetPosition((K) holder, position);
        setAnimation(((K) holder).getContainer(), position);
    }

    protected void onSetPosition(K holder, int position) {

    }

    public abstract void onSet(T item, K holder);

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    public void addObserverToFilter(Action1<List> task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<T> list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<T> nlist = new ArrayList<>(count);

            String filterableString;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i).toString();
                if (filterImplementation(filterString, filterableString.toLowerCase())) {
                    nlist.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mList = (ArrayList<T>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (task != null) {
                task.call(mList);
            }

        }

    }

    public List<T> getFilteredList() {
        return mList;
    }

    public List<T> getOriginalList() {
        return originalData;
    }

    protected boolean filterImplementation(String key, String door) {
        return door.startsWith(key);
    }

    protected void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position)

    {
        if (viewToAnimate == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }

    }
}
```

And The Handler:

```
public class Holders {

    public static class TextImageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


        private final View container;

        public TextImageHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container); 
            //add other view
            container.setOnClickListener(this);

        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }


}
```

Usage example for a another view:

```
public class ChildAdapter extends GenericRecycleAdapter<String,Holders.TextImageHolder> {


    public ChildAdapter (List<String> list, Context context) {
        super(list, context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onItem(String s) {
//triggers when container is clicked
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.some_row; //the id's here should be the same as in the Handler
    }

    @Override
    public void onSet(String item, Holders.TextImageHolder holder) {
        holder.text.setText(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks as awesome as hard it looks. I'll give it a try soon! thanks!

Comment: @MikelisKaneps .. i am trying to find a solution for my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856225/how-to-filter-two-or-more-recyclerviews-using-the-same-searchview ... i think your answer fits my need.. can you please suggest how to connect the Adapter to the Activities in which the `RecyclerViews` are... i would be greatly helpful.. if you also post a sample Activity , how to reference the `GenericRecycleAdapter` and the `ChildAdapter` in the Activities which contains the `RecyclerViews`